# Algorithm to differentiate a Neural Network with respect to features

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, gradient

I have trained a neural network to model a system and I want to use that neural network to optimize a cost function with only a  subset of features. My hypothesis function is parameterized by one subset of the features and the other subset of features is the feature set for the hypothesis function. In order to find the gradient of the hypothesis function I need to find the partial derivatives of the neural network with respect to the features. I have worked out the math on this and could probably design an algorithm but is there a standard efficient way of doing this?

I am planning on using a subset of the gradient vector and I was wondering what the optimal way to calculate the gradient vector is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not do neural networks, but logically the standard approach should be something like this:

$$F[x] = f_n\circ f_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ f_1[w_1 x+b_1] \implies F'[x]=w_1\frac{\partial F}{\partial b_1}$$

In other words, use standard backprop to get the derivative with respect to the bias $b_1$ on the first layer. Then multiply by the weights $w_1$ applied to the features $x$ that are input to this layer.

(This is just the chain rule applied to $F[z]$ where $z=w_1x+b_1$)

Comment: This works great, thanks! I am able to do gradient descent with this and get to a pretty low error.

Answer (score 0):

Still not quite understand the question, so my answer may be wrong... From my point of view, you may have 2 choices

- Only use a subset of feature to neural network
- Use all features, and get the gradient respect to all features, but only focusing on the components related to the feature you are interested in. In other words, get a subset the gradient vector.

Comment: I am going to use a subset of the gradient vector I wanted to know if there was a standardized way to calculate the gradient vector.

Comment: @user5505266 is that backpropagation algorithm?

Comment: backpropagation gets a gradient for the weights of the neural network.

Comment: @hxd1011 I basically just expanded your comment into a "pseudo-equation" answer :) I am not sure exactly what the OP had in mind, but perhaps something like generating [adversarial examples](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14908107896544813002)?